# AEM 6.1 PropertyIndex includedPaths

Tags: aem

I am creating a PropertyIndex in AEM with includedPaths property based on : http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/property-index.html (search includedPaths).
What i noticed is that even after includedPaths are added for a certain path the reindexing happens over the entire repository. Shouldn't the index be built only over the specified paths?

Here is the error.log:

```
06.01.2016 09:18:38.607 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing will be performed for following indexes: [/oak:index/myPropertyIndex]
06.01.2016 09:18:45.708 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing Traversed #10000 /etc/dam/viewers/s7viewers/html5/images/v2/ZoomResetButton_light_up_touch.png/jcr:content
06.01.2016 09:18:51.398 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']    org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing Traversed #20000 /jcr:system/jcr:nodeTypes/cq:VirtualComponent/jcr:propertyDefinition[2]
06.01.2016 09:18:53.222 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing Traversed #30000 /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/1c/01
 06.01.2016 09:18:54.185 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing Traversed #40000 /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/42/2d
06.01.2016 09:18:55.138 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing Traversed #50000 /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/68/91
06.01.2016 09:18:56.325 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing Traversed #60000 /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/8e/37

06.01.2016 09:19:37.995 *INFO* [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate Reindexing Traversed #140000 /libs/mobileapps/gui/components/pages/clientlibs/js.txt
```

My includedPaths doesnt even include /etc/ or /lib.. It refers to /content/dam

Comment: I think i got the meaning of includedPaths wrong. 
It says "The index is only used if the query has a path restriction that is not excluded, and part of the included paths." Its used for querying and not for indexing.
Similarly for excludedPaths "The index is only used if the query has a path restriction that is not excluded, and part of the included paths."

Answer (score 0):

Please set property

```
excludedPaths=[/var, /etc/workflow/instances, /jcr:system]
```

on the index as well as re-index that index. If still does not work, give oak core version and `http://host:port/oak:index.tidy.-1.json` output.